# Impossible to edit form with CasperJS when it is not empty

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I use CasperJS for form editing but I have a problem. When I have content in input, CasperJS can't edit this input.

Here, my script:

```
this.sendKeys(
    x('(//input[contains(@id, "DateSignatureContrat")])[last()]'), 
    '31/08/2015'
);
```

If I have a value on input, CasperJS doesn't change the value to 31/08/2015 but if this input is empty, CasperJS can.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, only add reset: true which will reset the input field before writing to it.

```
this.sendKeys(
    x('(//input[contains(@id, "DateSignatureContrat")])[last()]'),
    '31/08/2015',
    {reset: true}
);
```